# Storing std::cout to a Python variable

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I have [a Python function](https://github.com/thliebig/openEMS/blob/master/python/openEMS/openEMS.pyx#L450) that calls a C++ binary that uses [`cout << "Stuff" << endl;`](https://github.com/thliebig/openEMS/blob/master/openems.cpp#L125) to output things to the screen. How can I store the output to a variable?

```py
from openEMS import openEMS

def handler(event, context):
    FDTD = openEMS(NrTS=0, EndCriteria=0, TimeStepMethod=0)

    # I wish to redirect the output of this to a variable
    FDTD.Run("/tmp/engine", verbose=0, cleanup=True, numThreads=4)
```

I am currently able to see the output on the screen, and I do not mind writing to and reading from a file if it makes things easier. I would rather not have to modify the C++ code. Something like `python3 script.py > /tmp/output.log 2>&1` and reading from the file would work, but it's not very convenient as I'm using a Dockerized AWS Lambda function, and calling Python scripts multiple times seems inconvenient (but I'm open to whatever works):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3", "-m", "awslambdaric"]
CMD ["lambda_handler.handler"]
```

---

@Tim Robers - I can't post code blocks in comments, but if I understood correctly, I get

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

using:

```py
# Run simulation
f = open("/tmp/engine.log", "w")
stdout = sys.stdout.fileno()
sys.stdout.close()
os.dup2(f.fileno(), stdout)
FDTD.Run("/tmp/engine", verbose=0, cleanup=True, numThreads=4)

# Get unused primitives
with open("/tmp/engine.log", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Do we need to close the file somehow?

Comment: Inside the `FDTD.Run()` function, how are you actually running the subprocess?  This seems like a straightforward use of the `stdout=PIPE` option to the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) function family; not something specific to Docker or AWS's "Lambda" system.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy for pure Python code, because you can just do `sys.stdout = open('mylog.txt')`.  However, that doesn't change the C runtime library file handles, so C code will still go to the terminal.

It can be done, but it requires a little bit of trickery.

The idea is that you get the "file handle" for your original stdout (which happens to be 2, but that's beside the point).  You then use `os.dup2` make a duplicate of the log file handle, and duplicate it *as* the original stdout handle number.  Now, file handle #2 points to your file.

So, this actually works.  It redirects, runs a subshell, then puts things back where they were.

```
import os
import io
import sys

def redirect_stdout(to_fd, stdout):
    """Redirect stdout to the given file descriptor."""
    sys.stdout.close()
    os.dup2(to_fd, stdout)
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(os.fdopen(stdout, 'wb'))

f = open('mylog.txt','w')
stdout = sys.stdout.fileno()
saved = os.dup(stdout)

redirect_stdout( f.fileno(), stdout )
os.system('ls -l')
redirect_stdout( saved, stdout )

print("I'm back")
```

Here's how this works.  We save a copy of the original stdout's file handle.  By convention, that's file handle 2 (stdin is 0, sterr is 1).  We then use `dup` to create a copy of this file.  This simply creates a new file handle number that points to the original terminal file.

We then close the Python `sys.stdout`, which also closes file handle 2, making it available.  We then duplicate our *new* file's handle and force it to be numbered 2.  That file is now `STDOUT` to C code, or `cout` to C++ code.  We then reopen `sys.stdout` to use that file handle (which is what I omitted before).

To put things back to normal, we redo that process, but we duplicate the extra copy we made early on, and force *that* to be handle #2.

This was derived from *[Redirecting all kinds of stdout in Python](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/)*.

Comment: If I understood correctly (see my Edit for the updated code), I get "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

Comment: Right, that's what I mentioned at the bottom of my answer.  That code leaves Python's stdout in a bad state.  If you check the link I posted, it shows how to put things back.  I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this has been extremely helpful - I think I'm very close... One thing I noticed is that it doesn't capture the entire output. After further investigation, it looks like it calls some other part of the codebase that [uses `stream`](https://github.com/thliebig/CSXCAD/blob/master/src/CSProperties.cpp#L330) instead of `cout`. Any idea how to capture that too? That's actually the only thing I wanted to catch ultimately, but incorrectly thought it was using `cout`.

Comment: `cout` IS an `ostream`.  `stream` is a class, and `cout` is an instance.  Are they writing to a different file?

Comment: It seems that the stuff in [`openems.cpp`](https://github.com/thliebig/openEMS/blob/master/openems.cpp) are successfully written to the file and not printed to the screen, while [`CSProperties.cpp`](https://github.com/thliebig/CSXCAD/blob/master/src/CSProperties.cpp) are not written to the file but printed to the screen... Any way we could get the exact opposite result?

Comment: I don't have a clue how openEMS works.  That seems like a different question.

Comment: Sure, but my point is that for whatever reason, the C++ output is not being picked up in its entirety, so I'm trying to understand what has to be tweaked in our code.

Comment: Are they possibly writing to `cerr` instead?  What's different about it?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's `cerr` cause those are errors. I ended up splitting that part into another script and using `subprocess.run()` redirecting everything to a file seems to work fine. Thanks again for your help!